# Custom status bar and navigationbar from Google sign in controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I integrate Google sign SDK into my app. But I don't know how to change color of status bar and bar tint color of navigation bar also. I tried to change the colors with [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor] and [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle] from appdelegate, but nothing happened. I really need the help from you. Thanks.

Comment: Make a custom view for status bar and then change the color of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Custom status bar**

```
UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20);
addStatusBar.backgroundColor = //yourColor;
[self.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
```